# Visual studio won't let me move debug statement by dragging

Tags: visual-studio

My Visual Studio 2022 won't let me drag the current executed statement. I have seen this before, but can't do this on my machine for some reason..I can go into or skip to the next statement. But no way to move back.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Works for me in a simple program. You'll need to provide more details about your program and scenario (sure it's a debug build? where specifically are you trying to move from/to?). Maybe you can use Right click:Set Next Statement instead.

Comment: There are some limitations to that. E.g. it doesn't work if you're stopping at an exception.

Comment: This is with a .net Maui application when debugging on a local android device. When I try to drag the execution arrow, it doesn't even change the cursor type as well when dragging. Nothing happens. I have not looked at right clicking yet.